# Regex required for renaming file in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex for renaming file in c#. My file name is `22px-Flag_Of_Sweden.svg.png`. I want it to rename as `sweden.png`.

So for that I need regex. Please help me.

```
I have various files more than 300+ like below:

22px-Flag_Of_Sweden.svg.png   - should become sweden.png
13px-Flag_Of_UnitedStates.svg.png  - unitedstates.png
17px-Flag_Of_India.svg.png - india.png
22px-Flag_Of_Ghana.svg.png - ghana.png
```

These are actually flags of country. I want to extract Countryname.Fileextension. Thats all.

Comment: Why do you need a regex?

Comment: What are the rules (for finding the `sweden` part)? What have you tried?

Comment: @jglouie : what would you do If you need to rename 300+ files from a similar for to some desired one ?

Comment: I think you provided too few details, for you current question the answer can be: ^22px-Flag_Of_Sweden\.svg\.png$

Comment: I'd come up with a naming rule

Comment: @jglouie: What If you are saving image from internet.

Comment: Thanks Guys for your time and feedbacks... finally i did it via a tool called renameit. I am going to suggest it to my boss too... :) Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fileNames = new [] {
    "22px-Flag_Of_Sweden.svg.png"
    ,"13px-Flag_Of_UnitedStates.svg.png"
    ,"17px-Flag_Of_India.svg.png"
    ,"22px-Flag_Of_Ghana.svg.png"
    ,"asd.png"
};

var regEx = new Regex(@"^.+Flag_Of_(?<country>.+)\.svg\.png$");



foreach ( var fileName in fileNames )
{
    if ( regEx.IsMatch(fileName))           
    {
        var newFileName = regEx.Replace(fileName,"${country}.png").ToLower();
        //File.Save(Path.Combine(root, newFileName));

    }
}
```

Comment: since , i did it using some third party tool, but i am accepting your answer as it will required in future. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure how this would look in c# (although the regex is important and not the language), but in Java this would look like this:

```
String input = "22px-Flag_Of_Sweden.svg.png";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+_(.+?)\\..+?(\\..+?)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

System.out.println(m.matches());

System.out.println(m.group(1).toLowerCase() + m.group(2));
```

Where the relevant for you is this part :

```
  ".+_(.+?)\\..+?(\\..+?)$"
```

Just concat the two groups.

I wish I knew a bit of C# right now :)

Cheers Eugene.

Answer (score 0):

This will return country in the first capture group: `([a-zA-Z]+)\.svg\.png$`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know c# but the regex could be:

```
^.+_(\pL+)\.svg\.png
```

and the replace part is : `$1.png`